# How to distribute a Ruby script with required gems

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby script that is running into problems because the end-users don't have all the required gems. I've been looking into the issue and it seems packaging it as a gem is the best way to make sure it will work for anyone.

1. Is this the best way to distribute a Ruby script and not have to worry about the end-user not having a gem at runtime?
2. If I do it this way, how would the end-user run the script? Right now they are executing it using `ruby script_name` and I am writing a bash script to automatically run it for them.
3. Could I still have a bash script that could run the script if it's installed as a gem? Having a double-clickable file to run the script is a godsend for people who need to use it who aren't as technically inclined.

Comment: Getting a clean, cross-platform "clickable file" can be very challenging if not frustrating. What operating systems are you targetting?

Comment: I'm fairly certain I'm targeting Mac OS X, although the more I think about the more I think that the people I'm sending this off to may be on Windows machines.

Comment: The complexity ramps up exponentially for each operating system version you need to accommodate. Windows 7 and Windows 10 can be wildly different. What sort of application is this, and how much code is involved? While I'm a big fan of Ruby you might find that another language offers easier delivery options, for example [NW.js](http://nwjs.io) makes a ton of effort to be easily cross-platform portable. As far as I know no such thing exists for Ruby. There have been attempts in the past but they've all been abandoned.

Comment: There's also the [JRuby](http://jruby.org) option where you crush it all down to a `.jar` file and distribute it that way.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/phusion/traveling-ruby.

Comment: @nwk Nice find! If there's any group crazy enough to try and talented enough to succeed it's the Phusion team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm operating off of the assumption that your required gems are in a `Gemfile`. If you're having them run a bash script to run your Ruby script, have you considered adding `bundle install` to the bash script prior to having it run your Ruby script? This will install all the required gems before running the script.

Another option would be to setup a Docker container that already has all the gems installed and just automatically runs the Ruby script. This would get you around issues with your users having the wrong version of Ruby, but has the added cost of having them install Docker.

Comment: If I add that `bundle install` I'd also have to package the Gemfile with the zip I send out correct? That could definitely be an option -- although isn't bundler itself a gem? That would require them to install a gem, which ideally I want to avoid. I'll try taking a look into Docker.

Comment: yes, you would have to package the `Gemfile` with your `.zip` that you send out and yes `bundler` is a gem in and of itself. you can also add this to your bash script: `gem install bundler` ;)

Comment: haha! that's a solution I'm very interested in now! I'm assuming the script will stop and wait for bundler to be installed and then execute the next line?